# distributed queries are configured to run in single-threaded apartment mode

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, openrowset

I have sql server 2008 R2 64bit Developer's Edition Installed on my machine.

And Microsoft Office 2010 Professional 32bit.

I have been trying to import some Excel data from an Excel sheet into a sql server database. I have used the following query to do this:

**Query**

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
                'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\Files\BlueFile.xlsx;IMEX=1',
                'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

I understand sql server has disabled this feature by default as a security measure, however I executed the following statements to enable it.

**Configuration**

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

**Error Message**

Yet every time I execute the select statement to get data from Excel sheet I get the following error.

> Msg 7308, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 OLE DB provider 
>   'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' cannot be used for distributed queries
>   because the provider is configured to run in single-threaded apartment
>   mode.

Comment: As far as I am aware, you cannot use the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 driver to import from 32 bit Excel to 64-bit SQL Server. I believe you need the 64-bit Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable.

Comment: did you check if DTC service is running ?

Comment: Yes DTC is running I think the problem is what @MarkSinkinson has stated. I have office 32bit and Sql Server 64Bit. I have been doing some search online and a few places does recommend installing 64bit Access Driver to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mark has mentioned in the comments, you are running into a bit-level mismatch between driver sets.  You will need to either install a 64-bit installation of Office (specifically Excel in this case) or install a 32-bit installation of SQL Server and import the data to that instance.

Comment: You don't need the full blown 64 bit Excel. As Mark mentioned, there is a JET redistributable [AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Comment: `You cannot install the 64-bit version of Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 because you currently have 32-bit Office products` - check my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43176115/495455